# Fishpig Wordpress - Change Template

Tags: magento-1.9, third-party-module, wordpress

I have configured Wordpress with Magento using Fishpig extension and it works as expected. However, I need to set different template for one particular wordpress category(Id - 8)

```
<wordpress_category_8>           
        <reference name="wordpress_post_list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>wordpress/post/archive-list.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="setPostRendererTemplate">
                <template>wordpress/post/list/renderer/archive-category.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </wordpress_category_8>
```

Template is not changing even after adding the above code in local.xml

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please specify the reason for voting to close?